# Google Visualization Column Chart not showing all data

Tags: google-visualization, truncate

I have made a small column chart and all the data I have is not visible. Is it possible to get so that everything is visible without enlarging the width? Or is there any way to include a scrollbar so that everything can be seen?

For the code see:
[jsfiddle.net/danielbemler/4x8s3e4j/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/danielbemler/4x8s3e4j/5/)

As seen in the code below, the chart should display up to 300, but only shows up to 290.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var dataArray = [['Day','Matches']];
  for (var i = 0; i < 300;i++)
  {
    dataArray.push(['a' + i,i]);
  }
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);        
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data);
}
</script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can switch to using a continuous domain type ("number", "date", "datetime", "timeofday") then there are a few options available to you, the simplest of which is to use the `explorer` option (documentation hasn't been updated for ColumnCharts yet, but the explorer options outlined in the [LineChart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) configuration will work with the ColumnCharts):

```
function drawChart() {
    var dataArray = [['Day','Matches']];
    for (var i = 0; i < 300;i++) {
        dataArray.push([i,i]);
    }
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);        
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        hAxis: {
            format: '#a'
        },
        explorer: {

        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/qqmjqu8m/.  Zoom with the mouse wheel; pan by clicking and dragging.